# <md-list-item> in angular material js ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I'm new to this angular.
I have this issue. I have a code like this:

```
<md-list-item ng-repeat="c_comments in card_comments|filter:{ parent_id:'0' }">
   <img src=""></img>
    <md-list-item ng-repeat="c_comments in card_comments|filter:{ parent_id:'1' }">
     <img src=""></img>
       <md-list-item ng-repeat="c_comments in card_comments|filter:{ parent_id:'2' }">
        <img src=""></img>
           <md-list-item ng-repeat="c_comments in card_comments|filter:{ parent_id:'3' }">
           <img src=""></img>
           </md-list-item>
        </md-list-item>
     </md-list-item>
</md-list-item>
```

Here the parent_id is infinity ( 0,1,2,3,4,.....). So how i write this code in ng-repeat?

Comment: It required a little bit more brief

Comment: post your sample json response object

Comment: maybe it would be more efficient to have a function, which will create an object structure from this one dimensional array. This object structure would have the attributes each of your c_comments items has and an additional **sub_comments** attribute. Then i would use a simple directive for the recursive call. This directive would call itself in its template. This way you would keep your above example simple (at least in the toplevel html.

Comment: I have json like this: "card_comments":[{"id":3,"board_card_id":"PC2","parent_comment_id":0,"user_id":1,"comments":"This is tetin larevel this i oll ","date_time":1478759601},{"id":4,"board_card_id":"PC2","parent_comment_id":3,"user_id":1,"comments":"Testin kjjiolkikoll","date_time":1478759610},{"id":7,"board_card_id":"PC2","parent_comment_id":0,"user_id":1,"comments":"Some Testing...","date_time":1478760151},{"id":8,"board_card_id":"PC2","parent_comment_id":3,"user_id":1,"comments":"ssf gsfg ","date_time":1478760612}]}.

Comment: Any other idea to display this lists and sublists